# Permission denied to access property "handleEvent"

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm testing a web app in several browsers with the Selenium 2.45.0 grid.

At one point (I suppose when Bugsnag was added to the app) some find_element functions started to fail in Firefox (still work in Safari) with the 'Permission denied to access property `handleEvent` error.

It looks like there is a workaround for that:

```
adding 
$driver -> get_active_element();
before calling
$driver -> find_element...
```

But this is awkward.

Did anyone else face the same problem and find a more adequate solution?

Comment: what is a firefox version? I guess the problem with selenium and firefox capability, someone already faced this problems [check this] And as far as I remember before I got such errors at time to time. But I also would not recommend you to update firefox to the last version, because selenium 2.45 does not work pretty well with firefox 37 (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/452)

Comment: Yep. This is Firefox 37.0.2

Comment: well, in my case of using selenium 2.45 and firefox 37 - browser does not want even to start a new session, so I would recommend you or install firefox 36 or wait till selenium will get an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed by rescuing from this exception in Bugsnag [v2.4.8](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-js/commit/0478bf54778e534a2bf53dd129927b468e82447b).  Arguably selenium shouldn't be adding native handlers to in-page events, but oh well :).

Comment: Great!!! Selenium seems to work with Bugsnag 2.4.8 fine. No workaround needed anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

So my suggestion is that error occurs coz of not really good compatipability `firefox 37` and `selenium server 2.45` I would recommend you trying to install firefox 36 or wait till selenium web driver get update. Because in my case of using `selenium 2.45` and `firefox 37` it does not work at all - browser just opening and hanging till timeout.

Comment: I've tried FF36.0.4 - sadly the same error occurs. It looks like something wrong with Selenium 2.45. Calling get_active_element once on a page seems to work fine even with FF37 so let's stick with that for a while and wait for a new version of Selenium.